# Exception in .htaccess when accessing passworded URI for REST API

Tags: regex, apache, rest, .htaccess, webserver

I have set password authentication for website in .htaccess and would like to make an exception when the incoming request is for particular URI. Basically it works until one point.

The .htaccess looks like this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password"
AuthBasicProvider web-user
<RequireAny>
        Require valid-user
        Require env let_me_in
</RequireAny>
```

I've added:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/path1/path2/?rest" let_me_in
```

but in this case the questionmark is being omitted and authorizes me without password for */path1/path2/**rest*** but not for */path1/path2/**?rest***

if I change it to include an escape character like this:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/path1/path2/\?rest" let_me_in
```

it still requires authorization for /path1/path2/?rest

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [07/Apr/2020:21:01:50 +0200] "GET /path1/path2/?rest HTTP/1.1" 401 693 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/Safari"
```

/path1/path2/ is the root of the website

As a temporary workaround I have allowed all access for defined IP address - but this is not the desired way this should work

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx let_me_in
```

How can I get the SetEnvIf Request_URI work correctly for this particular case?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond: _“`REQUEST_URI` - The path component of the requested URI, such as "/index.html". **This notably excludes the query string** which is available as its own variable named `QUERY_STRING`.”_